# Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition JavaScript file all code in white color

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am working with `Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition` and it's been working great, I did get a message there is an update and updated it.

Now all my JavaScript code is white. The other languages such as C# / html etc. works great.

[image]

**I want my variables to me blue etc.**

I have tried following

1. Reset the settings Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings.
2. Closing the IDE and then reopening Visual Studio.
3. Restart.
4. Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors is not the solution.

**Visual Studio information**

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
Version 17.3.6
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.3.6+32929.385

Thanks,

Comment: This post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24259624/6530134) says to try refreshing intellisense cache, and also try to delete a file found in app data.  Perhaps try that?

Comment: Tried but no luck